# Compare a registry key to find if it is greater than or less than?

Tags: c#

I am currently working with the following code:

```
    public static bool checkFF86version(string FF86_version)
{
    RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
    .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
    //.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
    string displayFF86version;


    if (key != null)
    {
        foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
        {
            displayFF86version = subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion") as string;
            if (displayFF86version != null && displayFF86version.Equals(FF86_version))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        key.Close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would like to take the DisplayVersion from the registry key and check if it is greater than or less than the checked version (FF86_version)

I have tried converting the string to int, but seem to be stumped on the null reference. (shown below:)

```
    public static bool checkFF86greater(string FF86_greater)
    {
        RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        //.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        string displayFF86greater;


        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
            {
                displayFF86greater = subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion") as string;
                if (displayFF86greater != null && displayFF86greater.Equals(FF86_greater))
                {
                    string A = displayFF86greater;
                    string B = FF86_greater;

                    int versionA = Convert.ToInt32(A.Replace(".", string.Empty));
                    int versionB = Convert.ToInt32(B.Replace(".", string.Empty));

                    if (versionA > versionB)
                        return true;

                }

            }
            //key.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I know this may be very simple for most of you, but for some reason this has beat me up for two days, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Looking for:

```
        //Check FireFox version and compare it to a known good version
        if (!(checkFF86name("Firefox")))
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox is NOT installed" });
        else if (checkFF86name("Firefox") && (checkFF86version("33.0")))
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox is the latest version" });
        else if (checkFF86name("Firefox") && (checkFF86greater("33.0.1")))
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox is NEWER than checked version" });
        else
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Re-installing...." });
```

I think I tried that already using the following:

```
                    var checkedversion = FF86_greater.Split('.');
                    var installed = displayFF86greater.Split('.');

                    for (int i = 0; i < installed.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var currinstalled = in.Parse(installed[i]);
                        var currcheckedversion = int.Parse(checkedversion[i]);

                        if (currinstalled == currcheckedversion)
                            continue;
                        if (currinstalled > currcheckedversion)
                            return true;
                        if (currinstalled < currcheckedversion)
                            return false;
```

Unless I am going about this the wrong way!
Tried it like this, and still returning "False"

```
    public static bool checkFF86greater(string FF86_greater)
    {
        RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        //.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        string displayFF86greater;


        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
            {
                displayFF86greater = subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion") as string;
                if (displayFF86greater != null && displayFF86greater.Equals(FF86_greater))
                {
                    var version = displayFF86greater;
                    var parsedversion = Version.Parse(version);

                    var minimumversion = new Version(FF86_greater);

                    if (parsedversion >= minimumversion)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
            key.Close();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: No matter what I keep returning "False"

Comment: What does the string version of the number look like currently?

Comment: Here is what I am looking for: (UPDATED POST)

Comment: Removing the decimal(s) and converting to an integer is never going to work. Separate each of them into major, minor, and build numbers (`33`, .`0`, and `1` for `33.0.1`), convert each of them individually to integers, and compare them properly. If one of them (such as build) isn't available from the string, assign it a default value such as zero for the comparison.

Comment: Updated with the code I tried, I think that is what your referring to. Thanks for the help by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`Version.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.parse(v=vs.110).aspx). Then use two `Version` objects to compare.

Simple example:

```
// Get string from registry
// RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(blahblahblah)

var version = "32.0.1"; //Assume this string came from registry
var parsedversion = Version.Parse(version);

var minimumversion = new Version("33.0.1");

if (parsedversion >= minimumversion)
    Console.WriteLine("Your version is correct");
else
    Console.WriteLine("You need a newer version!");
```

Note: The Parse method is a convenience method; it is equivalent to calling the [Version(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hf9t2e(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor, also shown in this example (for `minimumversion`).

---

Other than that (from your code):

```
if (!(checkFF86name("Firefox")))
    ...
else if (checkFF86name("Firefox") && (checkFF86version("33.0")))
    ...
else if (checkFF86name("Firefox") && (checkFF86greater("33.0.1")))
    ...
else
    ...
```

You do realize that you access (and iterate over) the registry (worst case) some 5 times here do you? It won't kill you but it *also* won't hurt you to simply get the value once and then use that value in your comparisons.

Example:

```
Version ff86version = GetFF86VersionFromRegistry(); //Implement this method so that it simply returns FF's version as a Version object (or null if the key is not found)
if (ff86version == null)
  // FF not installed
else if (ff86version < new Version("33.0")
  // FF version less than 33.0 installed
else
  // Whatever
```

Also, it's not very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and prone to mistakes if you keep repeating things like `"Firefox"`. Use a variable / constant if you insist on calling the method in each if/else/else.

Comment: I will update the post, I am not sure why I cannot add more text in a reply.

Comment: If "you keep getting `False`" as a result then you should start debugging and simply use the variable inspector / watches and see what's happening. Step through the code with the debugger and make sure all variables contain the values you expect them to contain. Also (@your [latest/current update](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26568693/4)): please realize that `key.Close()` won't be invoked in many cases because you simple return (e.g. "exit" the method) beforehand. Consider using a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Very useful information, I am by no means a professional. I am trying to feel my way around in the dark.